# 907 Error after a new update of my app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have updated my app and published it the google play.
Now I get a lot of feedback of my users, that they can't update the app, because they get following error : 907
There are suggestion out there, like clearing the cash of GooglePlay Services and GooglePlay and probably this can be manually solved. But there are lots of users.

I try to understand, how can I prevent this as a Developer and why is this error coming now. My App is now 3 Years old and I regularly update my app (every 2 month) and I had never these kind of problems.

Has it probably something to do with the install location. If the app is installed on external memory. Could problably the correct setting of android:installLocation="????" in the Android Manifest be the solution ?

Is there something I can do as Developer ? (AndroidManifest.xml, changing the Android version, APK Version).

Can anyone help ?

**UPDATE**

I am not sure, but I see a difference in my AndroidManifest.xml File for different Apps. In my app which is updateable I have

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

In an app, which is not updateable I have:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

Could this be the problem ? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: The error only recently affects android 4.4+, so that would explain why it happens now if the app is 3 years old. You also would have published it against an old version of the play store, so that explains why it's a user-side problem that is solved by clearing the cache

Comment: The Problem also occurs with Android 5 according to a user. And how can I publish against an old or new Play Store ' How can I prevent this as a Developer ?

Comment: Did you not see the '+'? That means 4.4 and higher. Also, did you just update it after 3 years of not updating it? That is how you would have published to an old play store. And I would think you prevent it by updating your app more frequently. There is nothing you can do if something about how Google Play packages and installs apps prevents users from updating

Comment: I am updating regularly (every month). With 3 years I wanted to state, that I was never facing this issue.

Comment: Dear cricket. Do you think it could have to do something with the install-location of the app. Thats what I interpreted reading all the stuff about this problem. So I probably could prevent this by setting up the App with android:installLocation="internalonly" in AndroidManifest ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is there any reason you made it external?

Comment: Thats the default user request. They want to store everything external :-) Regarding my app, this setting is also about 3 years old.

Comment: You can write data to the external storage without having the app installed externally...

Comment: I know. Question is, if restrict the app for internal only will solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

In my app I declared the installation location like this :

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

This resulted in 907 errors in some cases (I myself couldn't reproduce it.)

I changed to:

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

and no problems anymore

Comment: We just had exactly the same problem with Scanbot app and pretty huge user base being affected. But luckily your solution worked - so I own you a beer :)